# str_to_date returning incorrect year value

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, str-to-date

I'm trying to convert a date with m/d/y format to yyyy-mm-dd.

```
select lastname, firstname, filingdate, str_to_date(filingdate, '%m/%d/%y') as reformattedDate
from Table;
```

For the returned dates, the month and day are correct, but the year is always 2020, even though the years in the original dates range from 2008 to 2021.

[Sample query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3yas.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

%y only recognizes 2 digits of year you must use %Y

> ```
> SELECT  str_to_date('01/01/2017', '%m/%d/%y'),str_to_date('01/01/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
> ```
>
> ```
> str_to_date('01/01/2017', '%m/%d/%y') | str_to_date('01/01/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
> :------------------------------------ | :------------------------------------
> 2020-01-01                            | 2017-01-01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae15866e493657d63c3ace70ccf183bb)*

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `%Y` rather than `%y`:

```
select lastname, firstname, filingdate,
       str_to_date(filingdate, '%m/%d/%Y') as reformattedDate
```

`%y` is for a two-digit year.  `%Y` is for a four-digit year.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!